# Highcharts not displaying chart but no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working on data visualization with Highcharts but since I started fetching my data from an API, it doesn't display anymore.

Data is response from the API. The information is gotten from the array (trying to mimic an API here), but this still doesn't display after a lot of tweaking and it doesn't display any errors.

It be helpful if one could also point out how to display highchart errors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      numericSymbols: null
    }
  });

  data = [{
    "chart": {
      "height": 500,
      "renderTo": "chart_ID",
      "type": "line"
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "line": {
        "dataLabels": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "enableMouseTracking": false
      }
    },
    "series": [{
      "data": [5000.0, 4100.0, 1000.0, 7500.0, 5100.0, 5000.0],
      "name": "Amount"
    }, {
      "data": [179, 86, 150, 393, 188, 322],
      "name": "Millage"
    }],
    "title": {
      "text": "Jhpiego Fuel Consumption"
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "categories": ["3 Jul", "12 Jul", "13 Jul", "14 Jul", "15 Jul", "16 Jul"]
    },
    "yAxis": {
      "max": 1000000,
      "title": {
        "text": "Fuel Price"
      }
    }
  }]
  apiData = data[0];

  highChartInfo = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: apiData.chart.renderTo,
      type: apiData.chart.type,
      height: 500,
      displayErrors: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: apiData.plotOptions.line.dataLabels.enabled
        },
        enableMouseTracking: apiData.plotOptions.line.enableMouseTracking
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: apiData.title.text
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: apiData.xAxis.categories
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: apiData.yAxis.title.text
      },
      max: apiData.yAxis.max
    },
    series: [{
        name: apiData.series[0].name,
        data: apiData.series[0].data
      },
      {
        name: apiData.series[1].name,
        data: apiData.series[1].data
      }
    ],
  }

  console.log(highChartInfo)
  $(data[0].chart.renderTo).highcharts(highChartInfo);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart_ID" class="chart" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: Hi , one issue i am seeing in your code is that you have forget to add `#` i.e : `$("#"+data[0].chart.renderTo)..` because `chart_ID` is id .

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, It worked.
Can't believe I forgot to add the Id selector :))